# Is pandoc's markdown to LaTeX conversion missing anything?

Tags: pandoc, markdown

That is, are there any features that the users of pandoc + MD wish they had?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know specifically? Since you can write your own filters, nothings *seems* impossible. Wether it's worthwhile or not to do so is a totally different question...

Comment: I think what I really want to know is whether there are any features missing from pandoc+MD that users of it would like to have. Let me update the question.

Comment: If you just want to have an overview, check the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss Spoiler: you can always write a [filter](https://pandoc.org/filters.html) to solve concrete problems. There are also a lot of tools to aid you, if anything comes up, i.e.:  https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Pandoc-Extras or https://github.com/search?q=pandoc or http://cdsoft.fr/pp/

Comment: Still: Your question is way too vague and general for this site. Any answer (cf.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508433/29873) is bound to be subjective and opinion based. Please consult the [TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Good to know, thank you!

Comment: If you want to use pandoc, just go ahead. You can always come back here (or the mailing list) if you hit a wall. And in the end the writing process is much nicer with MD and pandoc and you can always generate a tex-file and apply the finishing touches there, when the writing is done. That is: You won't loose anything.

Comment: If you are asking because you are not sure if pandoc is the right tool for you, I suggest you just try it out and see for yourself and don't wait what other people might think: Their priorities might be very different from yours. If you are (planning to get) involved in pandoc development and are looking for new features to implement then I applaud your intentions, but would like to mention that this site is probably the wrong forum to gather user feedback. Question here should usually have more or less objective answers and not opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀